# Format specifiers should be used instead of string concatenation in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, sonarqube, spring-mvc-test

I am writing code the below code

```
Logger.error("Error in x file :",+ e.getMessage());
```

But for the above line of code I am getting the error to use format specifiers instead of string concatenation. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Add to your class:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClassName.class);
```

and try this:

```
logger.error("Error in x file {}", e.getMessage());
```

Logging this way, you avoid performance overhead for strings concatenation.

More about spring-boot logging configuration [Zero Configuration Logging](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of concatenating the string with `+` (in `"Error in x file :",+ e.getMessage()`), you can use `String.format` to build the string instead:

```
Logger.error(String.format("Error in x file :%s", e.getMessage()));
```

Documentation on how Java String formatting works can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: For this it is not working showing the error can't make a static reference to non-static method.